# variable conflicts in rails index action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am a rails newbie so i hope someone can help me.

Here is my code

```
def index
  @todos = Todo.order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction)  #sorts table columns
  @todos = Todo.page(params[:page]).per(1)                 #pagination
  @todos = Todo.search(params)                             #search filter

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @todos }
  end
end
```

the sorting, pagination, and searching all work perfectly on their own, but obviously it is causing a conflict when declaring all three variables at once.

I'm not sure how to get around the problem of giving these variables different names, so that they'll still work in the context of the app.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you using meta_search and kaminari?

Comment: thanks for the reply. i tried your suggestion but get an error undefined method `page' for #<Tire::Results::Collection:0xb6d8c28> ive tried numerous variations of chaining the methods but to no avail. im using kaminari for pagination, elastic search with the tire gem for search

Answer (score 0):

You can chaining the calls:

```
 @todos = Todo.order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction).search(params).page(params[:page]).per(1)
```

I've changed the order a bit because, supposing you're using Kaminari, the pagination should always be the last method to call. This will work only if you're search method returns an ActiveRecord Relation.

*EDIT*

Reading the comments, I suppose you're using tire. It seems to support Kaminari but there is some effort you have to do. Please the a look at [this discussion](https://github.com/karmi/tire/pull/105). unfortunately, I'm not that familiar with Tire.